# ANGULARJS: How do I download PDF from URL received from server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, html, laravel

I want to download a PDF from URL received via $http GET() request from the server. The $http is initiated as soon as a button is clicked on the front-end. On the success of the $http is receive a URL of where the PDF file is saved and want it to download automatically on the success of the $http request. How do I achieve this ?

EDIT:

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="button clearfix">
  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left m-b" ng-click="generateReport()">Download Report</button>
</div>
```

Here's my controller (Angularjs) code :

```
$scope.generateReport = function() {
        $http.get('/pdfreport').success(function(response) {
            $scope.url = response;
        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log("Failed");
        });
    }
```

I want to download file from $scope.url when the button is clicked

Comment: `$window.location.href = pdfUrl`

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your success function create `<a>` element and assign your **$scope.url** (or **reposnse data**) to **href** attribute and then call *click* method of the created `<a>` element to download the file automatically:

```
  var createA = document.createElement("a")
  createA.setAttribute('href', $scope.url);
  createA.click();
```

Comment: It worked. The only problem is it doesn't download rather it opens, How do I achieve file download.
 for example: $scope.url = 'http://fastandfluid.com/publicdownloads/AngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf';

Comment: Add download attribute to <a> element which is supported in HTML5:
createA.setAttribute('download', 'fileNameWhatYouWant');
Also see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: @chiragshah, if download attribute creates problem (as it is HTML5 attributes). You can make other $http call to your laravel route where you can develop function to download file.